# VS 2013 hangs when publishing website to Azure cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, cloud, publish

I have a website in C# Visual Studio 2013, which was developed by another developer and is hosted on Azure cloud service. Whenever I make any changes and try to publish, Visual Studio hangs and I can't publish it. It is not showing any error message. Besides that I can successfully deploy it by building it, but as it's taking too much time and also costs money to client (as VS Team Services only provides monthly 60 minutes of free build, after that clients get charged for extra minutes). I am using following steps for publishing and it's works fine but after publishing starts Visual Studio hangs and is unresponsive.

The steps to publish the website are as follows:

1)      Open the solution in visual studio.

2)      Right click on the azure project in the solution explorer, and select publish.

3)      The first step in the wizard is to sign in, make sure to select your  credentials.

4)      The next step is settings, make sure environment is set to production and build configuration is set to release, then click next.

5) The final step is a summary, simply click the publish button.

I am very new to Azure so let me know if I need to make any setting during set up my project.

Comment: Also having this same issue.  I just upgraded to the latest vs 2013 2.7 sdk.  My guess is maybe there is an issue with that. What sdk are you using?

Comment: using **Azure SDK 2.6** experiencing same issue in **VS 2015** during **CSPACK** task in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets`...last message displayed in diagnostic build output is **Creating unencrypted package `C:\Projects\MyProject\MyApp\bin\Release\app.publish\MyAzureRole.cspkg`**...package never gets pushed to **vsdploy** blob container specified in publish profile property `AzureStorageAccountName`. Workaround is VS 2013 Update 5 for now...hopefully MS fixes this - recreating the Azure Project does not work. VS 2013 Update 4 also hangs, but Update 5 seems to fix it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, where VS would hang after the packaging phase of publishing a cloud-service to azure, or even just attempting to package instead of publish. Deleting the `.suo` file from the solution root folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I hit the same problem after installing the 2.8 SDK and tools. After checking out these answers I still had the problem, but found a solution.

Right click the Azure project in the VS2013 solution explorer, open project properties. Go to the application tab, and there's an "Upgrade" button to upgrade the project to the latest SDK. That did the trick for me.

[image]

Comment: This fixed my problem, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing the right steps to deploy using the wizard. However I don't have enough information to know what would cause this to hang. There are some documentation details about the wizard that might help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh535756.aspx

There are other ways to deploy to Azure, which may solve the issue. You can for example download a publish settings profile, and use this to deploy instead of the wizard. Details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/10/downloading-windows-azure-publish-settings-subscription-configuration-file.aspx

Or you can deploy continuously from Git - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step75

Both solutions will require some tinkering in the Azure portal or getting in with PowerShell but there's a lot of ways to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Doing these two things fixed it for me, not sure which:

- Clean build
- Server Explorer > (Had to re-enter Azure credentials)

VS2013 update 5.

Comment: solved my issue on  VS2015. Not necessary to do 1st step, but Re-enter credentials fix all issues.

Answer (score 0):

A related post found here..
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/virtualization/en-US/4e51b1f0-91c3-4ce9-9a15-a8d10f912c5b/publish-cloud-service-causes-visual-studio-2013-to-hang-crash?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

One user was able to get past the publish freezing by doing the following..

```
 So I did a line-by-line comparison between all of the files in that
 new project and everything in my existing one and found only two
 possible things wrong: 
 1) The version stamps (dates, really) in my
 files were not upgraded to reflect the latest version of the Azure
 tools.  I manually changed those in my existing project to match the
 garbage test project's date stamps. 
 2) My XML files had some empty
 sections that did not exist in the new project's files, so I simply
 removed those empty sections. 
 3) Beyond that, I also deleted my *.user
 file.
```

Specifically, I was able to remove schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4" from my ServiceConfiguration and ServiceDefinition files and it fixed the issue.

My guess is that your installed sdk version is different than the specified schemaversion.

Comment: Tried recreating azure project and removing *.user and stripping off **schemaVersion** - none of these worked for me in VS 2015 / Azure SDK 2.6. VS IDE just adds back the **schemaVersion** attribute after I remove it. Also removed all modules - web deploy, remote desktop, remote forwarder, etc. with no luck. The Windows Azure task **CSPACK** is freezing up the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above methods none worked for me. So this is for people who already tried above and still couldn't make it work.

=> Publish in Release mode :-)

Yes I was trying to publish in Debug mode which was causing it to hang till death ;-)